# matching text ranges with C++11 regexes

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying regexes in C++, and here is some code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::regex pattern("[a-z]+", std::regex_constants::icase);
  std::regex pattern2("excelsior", std::regex_constants::icase);
  std::string text = "EXCELSIOR";

  if (std::regex_match(text, pattern)) std::cout << "works" << std::endl;
  else std::cout << "doesn't work" << std::endl;

  if (std::regex_match(text, pattern2)) std::cout << "works" << std::endl;
  else std::cout << "doesn't work" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Now, from what I understand, both those matches should output `works`, but the first one outputs `doesn't work`, while the second one outputs `works` as expected. Why?

Comment: both should output "works". i tested it.

Comment: It looks like it should work, but fails on this online compiler: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fc8753739732402

Comment: [a more comprehensive set of tests on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd647a5e2cc1f712)

Comment: What compiler version are you using? (GCC < 4.9 has broken regex).

Comment: @Galik It's [reproducible] (http://ideone.com/UFeDO0). I'd suspect regex, is accurate, for explicitly specified character sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the rules described in [re.grammar], we have:

> — During matching of a regular expression finite state machine against a **sequence of characters**, two
>   characters `c` and `d` are compared using the following rules:
>   1. if `(flags() & regex_constants::icase)` the two characters are equal if `traits_inst.translate_nocase(c) == traits_inst.translate_nocase(d)`;
>   2. otherwise, if `flags() & regex_constants::collate` the two characters are equal if `traits_inst.translate(c) == traits_inst.translate(d);`
>   3. otherwise, the two characters are equal if `c == d`.

This applies to your `pattern2`, we're matching a sequence of characters and we have `flags() & icase`, so we do a nocase comparison. Since each character in the sequence matches, it "works".

However, with `pattern`, we don't have a sequence of characters. So we instead use this rule:

> — During matching of a regular expression finite state machine against a sequence of characters, **comparison
>   of a collating element range `c1-c2` against a character `c`** is conducted as follows: if `flags() & regex_constants::collate` is false then the character `c` is matched if `c1 <= c && c <= c2`, otherwise
>   `c` is matched in accordance with the following algorithm:
>
> ```
> string_type str1 = string_type(1,
>     flags() & icase ?
>         traits_inst.translate_nocase(c1) : traits_inst.translate(c1);
> string_type str2 = string_type(1,
>     flags() & icase ?
>         traits_inst.translate_nocase(c2) : traits_inst.translate(c2);
> string_type str = string_type(1,
>     flags() & icase ?
>         traits_inst.translate_nocase(c) : traits_inst.translate(c);
> return traits_inst.transform(str1.begin(), str1.end())
>         <= traits_inst.transform(str.begin(), str.end())
>     && traits_inst.transform(str.begin(), str.end())
>         <= traits_inst.transform(str2.begin(), str2.end());
> ```

Since you don't have `collate` set, the character is matched literally for the range `a-z`. There is no accounting for `icase` here, that is why it "doesn't work." If you provide `collate` however:

```
std::regex pattern("[a-z]+", 
                   std::regex_constants::icase | std::regex_constants::collate);
```

Then we use the algorithm described, which will do a no-case comparison, and the result will be "works". Both compilers are correct - though I find the expected behavior confusing in this case.

Comment: However, `collate` will make the pattern locale sensitive, which may result in unpredictable behavior on different systems. I think in this case, the better solution is to declare the character in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::regex pattern("[a-z]+", std::regex_constants::icase);
```

still restricts pattern matching for lower case letters. I'd suppose *character matching* as mentioned in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type) seems not to apply for explicitly specified character sets, which is what I would expect and makes sense to handle these if specified explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by case sensitiveness:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac21a962ee9f28fc

The flag `std::regex_constants::icase` is ignored by `std::regex_match`.

---

**Edit:**

Adding the flag `std::regex_constants::collate` solves the problem:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f57a2f2ff840c8be